# Build pcre2(10.33) static library for multi-width application

Tags: c++, c, регулярные-выражения, pcre

Столкнулся с проблемой сборки библиотеки pcre2, с параметром PCRE2_CODE_UNIT_WIDTH 0, для UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32, сборка проходит без проблем, однако при сборке для multi-width application, возникают ошибки:

```
[bcc32c Error] pcre2_auto_possess.c(273): unknown type name 'PCRE2_UCHAR'
[bcc32c Error] pcre2_auto_possess.c(274): unknown type name 'PCRE2_UCHAR'
[bcc32c Error] pcre2_auto_possess.c(306): unknown type name 'PCRE2_SPTR'
[bcc32c Error] pcre2_auto_possess.c(307): unknown type name 'PCRE2_SPTR'
[bcc32c Error] pcre2_auto_possess.c(310): use of undeclared identifier 'PCRE2_UCHAR'
[bcc32c Error] pcre2_auto_possess.c(311): use of undeclared identifier 'PCRE2_UCHAR'
[bcc32c Error] pcre2_auto_possess.c(312): use of undeclared identifier 'PCRE2_SPTR'
```

Очевидно тип не определён из-за директивы препроцессора, т.к. он использует для случаев UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32 следующее объявление:

```
#define PCRE2_JOIN(a,b) a ## b
#define PCRE2_GLUE(a,b) PCRE2_JOIN(a,b)
#define PCRE2_SUFFIX(a) PCRE2_GLUE(a,PCRE2_LOCAL_WIDTH)

#define PCRE2_UCHAR                 PCRE2_SUFFIX(PCRE2_UCHAR)
#define PCRE2_SPTR                  PCRE2_SUFFIX(PCRE2_SPTR)
```

А для сборки с параметром PCRE2_CODE_UNIT_WIDTH 0:

```
#elif PCRE2_CODE_UNIT_WIDTH == 0
#undef PCRE2_JOIN
#undef PCRE2_GLUE
#define PCRE2_SUFFIX(a) a
```

В pcre2.h определены следующие типы:

```
typedef uint8_t  PCRE2_UCHAR8;
typedef uint16_t PCRE2_UCHAR16;
typedef uint32_t PCRE2_UCHAR32;

typedef const PCRE2_UCHAR8  *PCRE2_SPTR8;
typedef const PCRE2_UCHAR16 *PCRE2_SPTR16;
typedef const PCRE2_UCHAR32 *PCRE2_SPTR32;
```

В связи с этим интересует вопрос, возможна ли сборка для "multi-width application". Если ответ да, то как?

Comment: Что такое multi-width в вашем понимании?

Comment: на сколько я понимаю, надо собирать все три (или две) библиотеки, а в своём коде уже определять `PCRE2_CODE_UNIT_WIDTH` в `0`, использовать варианты функций с потфиксами, а потом линковать со всеми нужными вариантами библиотеки...